# Is it possible to pick which column getting invalid number exception while selecting from table at run time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a requirement to move records from one table1 to another table2 both the table having same column name but the data type is different, while selecting from table1 with data type conversion I'm getting "invalid number" exception, i need to know which column getting the exception this all happening at run time. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Put the table DDL and complete error.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query before inserting for your `table1` and `table2`  and get the columns for which it is not matching.

```
SELECT a.table_name source_table,
       b.table_name dest_table,
       a.column_name,
       a.data_type source_type,
       b.data_type dest_type
FROM user_tab_columns a
JOIN user_tab_columns b ON a.column_name = b.column_name
AND a.table_name = 'TABLE1'
AND b.table_name = 'TABLE2'
AND a.data_type != b.data_type;
```